# How to disable Windows 10 calendar?

Tags: windows-10, calendar, windows-store-app

I use Outlook (connected to an on prem Exchange server) for my mail and calendar needs.

Out of sheer curiosity, I configured the built-in Windows 10 Calendar app to synchronize with my Exchange account.

It worked but I didn't like it so I removed the account in the app (by going into settings, then accounts, then delete). I do not have any accounts left (save for the default Microsoft one, which is empty anyway).

The Calendar app is now empty (there are no more events - they were deleted together with the account) **but the reminders still fire up at each meeting.**

These are reminders for the now-gone meetings brought in via the Exchnage synchronization.

**How to get rid of them?**

I believe that this is a bug in Windows 10 so, alternatively, **how to remove the Calendar (and probably Mail) app so that there is nothing to trigger the reminders?**

Comment: Have you tried simply turning off the notifications:  `Start > Settings > System > Notifications and actions`, and then scroll down to **Get notifications from these senders** on the lower-right and change Calendar to **Off**.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k: I used your very good advice and shut down the reminders. The core issue is still there, though (= how come the reminders are still there in the first place)